# Silverstripe 4 add GridField in cms tab

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Dear Silverstripe 4 users, i need someone to explain me how to slove my problem. Am building ecommerce module, i create data object for insert new proucts and categories without any problems.

Probelm start when i try to create related products for new product. I do that from `has_many` relatian and `ListboxField` and that is work good but i dont want to do that with list box filed. I want to create new tab like `(Root.RelatedProducts)` and there to have gridfield where i can add existing product.

I know to create grid with headers, actions and other grid configuration. When i create grid i only can add new product.

How to implement to chose existing product and show in grid in specific tab?

class Product extends Page
{

```
private static $has_many = [
    'RelatedProducts' => Product::class
];

public function getCMSFields()
{
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

  $gridFieldConfig = GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create();


    $gridFieldConfig = GridFieldConfig::create()->addComponents(
        new GridFieldToolbarHeader(),
        new GridFieldAddNewButton('toolbar-header-right'),
        new GridFieldSortableHeader(),
        new GridFieldDataColumns(),
        new GridFieldPaginator(10),
        new GridFieldEditButton(),
        new GridFieldDeleteAction(),
        new GridFieldDetailForm()
    );
    $gridField = new GridField("RelatedProducts", "Related products", $products,  $gridFieldConfig);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add existing products to the relation, you can use another gridfield config. Silverstripe has some predefined configs available and you took the `Gridfield_RecordEditor`.

If you use [`Gridfield_RelationEditor`](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/4/src/Forms/GridField/GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor.php) you also get a component to search for existing records. From the docblock of RelationEditor:

> Similar to {@link GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor}, but adds features to
> work on has-many or many-many relationships.
>
> Allows to search for existing records to add to the relationship,
> detach listed records from the relationship (rather than removing them
> from the database), and automatically add newly created records to it.

You can configure it more like this:

```
 GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create()
    ->getComponentByType('GridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter')
    ->setSearchFields('MyField');
```

By the way: I'd use a `many_many` relation, as a product could be related to more than one product.

Comment: This sounds good. I will try this today and i will inform you. Thannks for answer.